# How to get more readable diff for codeception assertEequals string?

Tags: php, xml, diff, codeception

Assume I want to assert if these XML snippets are the same:

```
public function assertXmlIsSame() {

        $leExpectedXml = <<<XML
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
XML;

        $leActualXml = <<<XML
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder
    </heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
XML;
  

    $this->assertEquals(
        $leExpectedXml,
        $leActualXml,
        'le xmls should be the same'
    );
}
```

I get the output:

```
Fail  Failed asserting that two strings are equal. ( -Expected | +Actual ) 
- '<note>
-     <to>Tove</to>
-     <from>Jani</from>
-     <heading>Reminder</heading>
-     <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
- </note>'
+ '<note>
+     <to>Tove</to>
+     <from>Jani</from>
+     <heading>Reminder
+     </heading>
+     <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
+ </note>'
```

which is not helpful, as the whole XML is dumped even with equals line.

If I create a `SebastianBergmann\Diff\Differ` and dump that diff:

```
$diff = (new Differ())->diff($leExpectedXml, $leActualXml);
codecept_debug($diff);
```

The output looks like this:

```
  --- Original
  +++ New
  @@ @@
   <note>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
  -    <heading>Reminder</heading>
  +    <heading>Reminder
  +    </heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
```

Much more readable and more what I was expecting from codeception.

Is there for codeception only to hightlight the diff for changed parts? As esp. if the xml structures become larger, it's almost impossible to see the difference with the default codeception diff output.

Comment: Please make Codeception use Differ and raise a pull request.

Comment: @Naktibalda I'll try :) I will let you know how I proceed.

Comment: @Naktibalda Interestingly I just realized that the Differ from Bergmann is already in use 0.o

Comment: I think I see the issue in `src/Codeception/Subscriber/Console.php` as the message seems custom build in order to get the coloring, which then destroys the readability of the diff. I will open an issue on github and work on the PR in due time; yet I would not continue chatting here ;)

Comment: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3230

Comment: it's an issue on codeception's side https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3230